# Fill in missing data by breaking down values from one day

Tags: r, datetime

During data recording, there are sometimes power outages and then the consumption from several days aggregates within one day and is unreasonably large.

Sample data

```
df<-data.frame(dayofmonth=c(5,6,7, 8, 9, 10 ,11,12,13,14),
               measurement=c(301589, 301599, 301602, NA, NA, 301637.5, 301683.8, 301693.1, 301702.9, 301713.2)) %>% 
  mutate(hotwater=c(0, diff (measurement)))

ggplot (df) + 
  geom_col (aes (x = factor(dayofmonth), y = hotwater))
```

In this specific case, data for four days require corrections and supplements

```
B <- (301637.5 - 301599)/4
```

I want the final output to look something like this:

```
df<-data.frame(dayofmonth=c(5,6,7, 8, 9, 10 ,11,12,13,14),
               measurement=c(301589, 301599, 301599 + B, 301599 + 2*B, 301599 + 3 * B, 301637.5, 301648.3, 301657.6, 301667.4, 301677.7)) %>% 
  mutate(hotwater=c(0, diff (measurement)))

ggplot (df) + 
  geom_col (aes (x = factor(dayofmonth), y = hotwater))
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are try to interpolate the missing values based on the last value and the next one. The `zoo::na.approx()` function. Based on your first `df` this would be:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(measurement = zoo::na.approx(measurement),
         hotwater=c(0, diff (measurement)))
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-10/topics/na.approx